# Is it possible to set a per-profile HISTFILE in iTerm2?

Tags: terminal, iterm, zsh

Let's say I have a "Work" profile in iTerm2 and want to set a different `HISTFILE` for this profile, called `.zsh_history_work`, so that I don't see my work commands showing up in my regular profiles.

I know that it's possible for me to switch to the different `HISTFILE` by writing `HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history_work` every time I open a new window with the "Work" profile. Is there a way to make this automatically happen so that I don't need to run the command all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, go to iTerm2 Preferences > Profiles > [Select "Work" Profile] > General > Command > Send text at start, and enter the following:

```
HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history_work
```

This should work as long as you're not using `oh-my-zsh`. If you are, the `HISTFILE` is loaded during the `.zshrc` startup. This will cause commands to be written to the proper "work" history file, but read from the regular `~/.zsh_history` file. To combat this, we use a different command:

```
fc -p ~/.zsh_history_work
```

This will allow you to both read and write from the work history file.

One more thing: this command will show up every time you open a window or tab with the Work profile. To prevent this from happening, type the following instead:

```
fc -p ~/.zsh_history_work && clear
```

This will automatically clear the page so that you're left with a blank terminal with your desired history file!